# Virtual Development Environment Performance - .NET Development

Tags: visual-studio, development-environment, virtualization

I have the following setup for my daily/main/only development environment

Hardware/Tin = 4gb ram, 2.6ghz dual core CPU, 2x250gb HD's, usual array of periperhals

One the tin above, I currently have Windows XP installed, in Windows XP I have VMWare Workstation installed and I run a Windows Server 2003 deelopment environment.  This includes,Visual Studio 2003/2005/2008, Sql Sever 2005/2008, Full MS Office suite, some producitivity tools (e.g. Redgate Sql/Data Compare, DevXpress Coderush, TestDriven.net etc).

I have problems with this, it runs slow (15 minutes to boot), the Watch/Autos windows in VS freeze up when debugging, I can't have more than 2-3 copies of VS open, the Errors window freezes up, WinGrep and COm+ constantly runs out of Virtual Desktop Memory and so forth (In fact, I would attribue most of the issues to Virtual Desktop Memory)

Now, I've tried every tweak in the book, I have second HD for VMWare, my paging file is on a differnt drive, I've adjusted my Ram split between guest and host, I've hacked the reg key for Virtual Desktop Memory and all of this to no avail.

Now, I could increase my Ram or CPU, but I'm not able to.

My question is, has anybody experienced the above, and if so, how did you solve it?  Did you try ESXi? or shift your environment to raw tin?

Comment: If my understanding is correct, you should see a nice bump if you use a 64-bit OS and a processor that supports virtualization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, you've tried just about every tweak in the book. I'd suggest that you should just move to native for your main setup, and restrict VM use for testing.

I use a VM as my main dev env, but I don't run as much stuff as you, so I don't hit a big performance wall.

Comment: Went down this route eventually, turns out with WK8 and W7 you can move a drive containing the OS install to a completly different hardware platform and so long as you have the drivers, it will still boot up, which gives me the portability I wanetd (ofc the having to move physical drives around is a pain, but I can live with it)

Comment: Cool - I didn't know that. Could come in handy later, when I upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the trick you didn't try was to run less things on your VM. 2-3 copies of VS are a recipe for slowness. Running Sql Server, same thing. Bump up memory would be good, but at least run services (iis, sql server) on another vm or better yet, another box. You are taxing your VM waay too much, it is not VM's fault.

Comment: With a boottime of 15 minutes, there probably still are some things he can try.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you run into most of the time on VPS is IO wait.

Do you run your virtual machine off of a disk image, if so try defragmenting your drive.
Or did you dedicate a partition to it?

Edit:
I would suggest to:

- either try defragmenting the drive that has the disk image
- either try dedicating a partition to the virtual machine, instead of using a disk image all together. (ideally the first partition on the drive, since this will have the lowest random access time)

Running off a disk image works, but since you're working on top of a filesystem, the disk image might be fragmented throughout the disk.

Good luck, hope it helps...

Comment: I run the VM of a separate/secondary disk, not from the same disk as the guest VM

Comment: If you run off a disk image (a file on the filesystem), fragmentation is something to reckon with. So is it a disk image, or did you create a separate paratition for the virtual machine?